# How can I confirm the correct pinout of a USB <> RS232 null modem cable?

Tags: rs232

A loopback test with HyperTerminal, or something similar, will confirm the cable itself is working.

But I want to know if the pinout configuration is indeed as expected... i.e. That pins 2 and 3 are reversed.

Comment: LED,  resistor and hyperterminal?

Comment: An oscilloscope

Answer (score 0):

Realterm has a "pins" tab, and buttons to force the state of the individual output pins, including TX (break functions) to identify them

Comment: That's what I was looling for... I'll give it a try. Thanks